# NullPointerException when accessing array of JTextAreas

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtextarea

I'm making an assignment planner, where one enters the assignment for the day in a JTextArea. I made the JTextAreas static, so I could access them outside the class. To clean up my code, I decided to use for loops and put the JTextAreas into static instance variable- arrays. But, when I try to access a JTextArea through an array, I get a NullPointerException. Here is an example of the declaration of a JTextArea:

```
static JTextArea MondayEng;
```

The arrays (one per subject) are declared as so:

```
static JTextArea[] Eng =  new JTextArea[]{
    MondayEng,
    TuesdayEng,
    WednesdayEng,
    ThursdayEng,
    FridayEng
};
```

And then there is a `JTextArea[][]` which contains the arrays:

```
static JTextArea[][] subjs = new JTextArea[][] {Eng, Hist, Math, Sci, Lang};
```

The JTextAreas are instantiated inside the JFrame (Called PWin), like this:

```
MondayEng = new JTextArea();
MondayEng.setBounds(664, 68, 153, 100);
contentPane.add(MondayEng);
```

I'll try to get the contents of the JTextAreas like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < PWin.subjs.length; i++) { // Iterate through subjects
        String sub = subjects[i]; // Store the current subject in a variable
        for (int y = 0; y < days.length; y++) { // Iterate through days in week             
            String day = days[y]; // Store the current day in a variable                
            String str = PWin.subjs[i][y].getText(); // Get the text of the JTextArea currently selected, plop it in a string
```

The this is exception when saving files:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PSave.<init>(PSave.java:19)
    at PWin$1.actionPerformed(PWin.java:262)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6373)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6138)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4735)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2143)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4621)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4282)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4212)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2129)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:679)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:638)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:636)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:652)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:650)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:649)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Any help will be appreciated a lot!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your problem is that at the time you are creating your arrays, the JTextAreas haven't been constructed yet. Java is pass by value, so when you pass in the names of JTextAreas that are to be constructed later it is the same as passing null.

Comment: Thank you! So, I should declare the JTextAreas like this, `JTextArea MondayEng = new JTextArea`?

Comment: Yes and make sure they are declared before you declare your array

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace this:

```
MondayEng = new JTextArea();
MondayEng.setBounds(664, 68, 153, 100);
contentPane.add(MondayEng);
```

with:

```
Eng[0] = new JTextArea();
Eng[0].setBounds(664, 68, 153, 100);
contentPane.add(Eng[0]);
```

Otherwise, the array `Eng` still contains `null`s, and you are just creating a new `JTextArea` object and making `MondayEng` refers to that object instead of pointing to what `Eng[0]` is pointing to.

However, the more correct answer would be constructing the `JTextArea`s just before passing them to the array. Something like:

```
MondayEng = new JTextArea();
MondayEng.setBounds(664, 68, 153, 100);
contentPane.add(MondayEng);

// ...

static JTextArea[] Eng =  new JTextArea[]{
    MondayEng,
    TuesdayEng,
    WednesdayEng,
    ThursdayEng,
    FridayEng
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since JTextArea[][] subjs is a double dimensional array you need to take care of generating the array properly. The way you created is a single dimensional array. Ideally you may need to create like

```
JTextArea[][] subs = new JTextArea[][]{ {Eng, Hist, Math, Sci, Lang} };
```